# 144hz Monitor on DVI to HDMI on 1400x1050@60hz

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, external-display, refresh-rate

I put this question in Arquade but was told to move it here:

I recently bought an AOC G2770PF 144hz 1ms Monitor which you can check out here: [https://www.amazon.com/AOC-G2770PF-Freesync-DisplayPort-Speakers/dp/B013YIR5WU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013YIR5WU)

Currently, i don't have a Desktop Computer so I am running this on my laptop you can check it here: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B015PYZI8E/ref=olp_product_details?_encoding=UTF8&me=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015PYZI8E)

Anyways, The Monitors 'Extra' Tab on the OCD shows:

Horizontal Refresh Rate: 68KHz

Vertical Refresh Rate: 60Hz

Which, of course, is odd considering the monitor literally shows 144hz on the Frame. I am using a Male HDMI and Male DVI-D cable to connect the two (I'm not sure if this is the problem or not) I mainly play csgo on 1400x1050 resolution so I thought that since HDMI 1.3+ can (apparently) support 144hz @ 1920x1080 that I could of course play on 144hz on a resolution less than 1920x1080. when I checked the csgo console command "mat_info" it said that I was running 1400x1050@60hz what is the problem? Also im not to sure what the version of my laptop's HDMI port supports (1.3,1.4,2.0 etc;) would this mean that i cant run on 144hz on HDMI to HDMI?

Heres what it says on display adapter properties:
[DisplaySettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nazpX.png)

Answer (score 1):

The display’s specs ([manual](http://eu.aoc.com/en/gaming/products/g2770pf/support) page 58) are very clear on this:

> Vertical scan range G2770PF: 35Hz~146Hz    for DP only

Some other model can also do it over **Dual Link** DVI, though it’s not entirely clear whether the G2770PF can. It most certainly won’t work over Single Link DVI or HDMI.

Comment: Thanks for the information, since my laptop only has HDMI what is the maximum resolution that i can play on with 144hz or even 120hz?

Comment: This isn’t a bandwidth problem. It’s a limitation with the display’s internal design. Since FreeSync requires DisplayPort anyway, they simply skipped support for higher refresh rates on other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI 1.2 is limited to HD resolution @60Hz. You want DisplayPort or DVI.
HDMI 1.3 and 1.4 are limited to 1920 × 1080 at 120 Hz.

Not sure what the newer HDMI standards support for HD refresh rates.

You will need a 1.3 or 1.4 HDMI cable and ensure your laptop has HDMI 1.3 or newer support. Note that you can get high quality HDMI cables for less than $10 on the internet, those $50 or even $1500 cables are absolutely the exact same ...

Sources: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI
https://www.hdmi.org

Comment: actually depends on the HDMI version - I have a monitor that does 4k30 and another one that does 4k60 - and my video card will do 4k60.  HDMI will easily do better than 4k60 with the right video card and possibly cable

Comment: Indeed, I was initially implying HDMI 1.2  ...

Comment: I dont need to use it on 1920x1080 though so could i still technically use it on a resolution less than that (1400x1050)?